# Where on Earth is this background image in Windows from?

Tags: where-on-earth, locate-this, lock-screens

Where exactly is this location located?

[image]

I have tried to reproduce this image several times in **Windows 10 login page**, but I failed.

What's the name of this location?

Comment: If you click on that "Like what you see?" line at top right, it will tell you the details of what and where this is.

Comment: @AleksG I know that. You are not seeing this line: I have tried to reproduce this image several times in Windows 10 login page, but I failed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like [Cascata dos Anjos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascata_dos_Anjos) in Ponta do Sol on the Portuguese island Madeira, and the photo was made by [Marco Bottigelli](https://www.marcobottigelli.com/tours/photo-tour-madeira/).

[image]

Comment: What's interesting is that in the original photo there is a person in the waterfall, but in the Windows screen saver there is no person.

Comment: @PeterM yes, there must have been some postprocessing. I noticed it too, wondered if it was *really* the same photo, but it must be; just check the patterns in the sea and the waves on the shore.

Comment: I checked several other elements of the photo as well.  My only guess would be that MS didn't want to pay for a model release of who ever is in that waterfall, and decided the easiest way legalistically was simply to edit them out.

Comment: @PeterM: Or they couldn't _find_ the person, and, as such, had no way of getting a release from them.

Comment: @Vikki Given the professional status and experience of the photographer, I'd guess that he knows exactly who the model was.

Comment: It feels more likely to me that that in the travel image the person is edited IN.

Comment: @Vikki, do you need a release for someone who can't be identified who's in a public place? It's also plausible that they prefer to avoid having people in the frame (I've not been paying much notice to the photos shown so far, so maybe I'm miles off!)

Comment: @PeterM Windows 10/11 photos generally don't have any humans in them, ever. I don't think it's related to any legal issues.

Comment: @ThomasRedstone The requirement of a release for is going to depend on the jurisdiction. Given that Windows is used globally, the easiest legal solution is simply to not include people.  As JonathanReez pointed out, Windows screen savers don't have people in them. I can't say whether this is stylistic or legal, but the legal implications are genuine.